# How to create object[][] from Hashtable dynamically?

Tags: c#, arrays, dictionary

I am writing a wrapper around web services by third party. The interface looks like this:

```
public System.Data.DataSet GetXxxx(string functionName, object[][] parameters)
```

Some of the `functionName`s use no parameters, some of them use one, some of them more, like this (from their doc):

```
parameters[0][0]: @key_one
parameters[0][1]: value for @key_one
parameters[1][0]: @key_two
parameters[1][1]: value for @key_two
```

To generalize the wrapper, I was thinking about passing `Hashtable` or `Dictionary<string, object>`, and to create the `parameters[][]` inside the wrapper dynamically.

How can I do that?

**Update:** Actually, the parameter pairs have to *keep the order*. Do, I have to change the interface to something like:

```
using ListOfParamPairs = List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>;

...

public static DataSet GetXxxx(string functionName, ListOfParamPairs parameters)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: If I uderstand you right; To `var dictionary = parameters.ToDictionary(line => line[0].ToString(), line => line[1]);`? Back: `object[][] parameters = dictionary.Select(pair => new object[] {pair.Jey, pair.Value}).ToArray();`

Comment: `Dictionary<K, V>` *doesn't* have any order. If order of the pararmeters matters, yes, you have to switch to `List<KeyValue<K, V>>` or alike

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you right, you can try *Linq*:

From `object[][]` to `Dictinary<string, object>`:

```
 using System.Linq;

 ...

 Dictionary<string, object> dictionary = parameters
 //.Where(line => line.Length == 2 && line[0] != null) // valid params only
   .ToDictionary(line => line[0].ToString(), 
                 line => line[1]);
```

Back to `object[][]`:

```
 using System.Linq;

 ...

 object[][] parameters = dictionary
   .Select(pair => new object[] {pair.Key, pair.Value})
   .ToArray();
```

**Edit:** In case we have to switch to `List<KeyValuePair<String, Object>>` (we want to *preserve the initial order*; dictionary's pairs are not in order):

**To:**

```
 List<<KeyValuePair<String, Object>> list = parameters
   //.Where(line => line.Length == 2 && line[0] != null) // valid params only  
   .Select(line => new KeyValuePair(line[0].ToString(), line[1]))
   .ToList();
```

**Back:** (technically, the same)

```
  object[][] parameters = list
    .Select(pair => new object[] {pair.Key, pair.Value})
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks Dmitry. Actually, I have to preserve the order of the parameters. Can you comment on the update?

Comment: @pepr: If we switch from `Dictinary<string, object>` to `List<<KeyValuePair<String, Object>>` we have to modify `To` part a bit (see my edit, please)

Comment: In your opinion, is the `List<<KeyValuePair<String, Object>>` the way to go, or would you choose another way? (I am thinging about how the parameters are to be written explicitly when calling the warapper.)

Comment: @pepr: Well, `List<KeyValue<string, object>>` is quite good choice, providing that you don't have many (say, thousands) parameters which you address by their name. Possible (but in my opinion, worse) alternative is `List<Tuple<string, object>>`